# Why so careful about honorifics?

Tags: prophets, respect, salawat

Muslims will pretty much always include some honorific after the names of prophets and other religions figures (such as PBUH, etc.) Why are people so careful to always do this *every time*? Is this based on some legal source, or is it simply out of respect?

Comment: out of love&respect by some muslims I know for a fact. don't know about any legal bindings.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why do Muslims add "peace be upon him" after names of important people?](http://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/1/why-do-muslims-add-peace-be-upon-him-after-names-of-important-people)

Comment: @servant-of-Wiser This is a different question. That asks for the reason why one would do it.  This asks why people _always_ do it.

Comment: Ah what? I'm sorry, if you have the reason, then whether you do it always or not always is up to a particular person. There are many people out there who don't even bother to write (pbuh) even after the name of Prophet Muhammad. Then I'm afraid it could be off-topic, here i.e. about behavior of Muslims.

Comment: @servant-of-Wiser That's not off topic.  I asked if there is a legal reason to do it.

Comment: I hope you'll get an answer from [What are the rules of saying “peace be upon him”?](http://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/140/what-are-the-rules-of-saying-peace-be-upon-him)

Comment: More over it depends on whom you ask, Sunnis might not say it compulsory hence not always required, so it is just respect. But, Shias might show you the hadith which I showed in my answer regarding Prophet Muhammad (pbuh) hence thereby implying it "always". It depends. And no compulsory regarding other prophets and notable figures and hence only just respect and no legal source.

Answer (score 2):

Love and respect is the ultimate reason for the honorifics for people that sacrificed their whole lives for us. There are also hadiths that encourage praising our Prophet (SAW) - not only by the person that has mentioned him, but also by the people that have heard his name being mentioned. I believe using an honorific after the names of other religious figures is derived from this.

The Messenger of Allah said: "Whoever sends one salaam (صلى الله عليه وسلم‎ ṣall Allāhu ʿalay-hi wa-sallam) upon me, Allah will send ten upon him."
—Abu Hurayrah

Allah and His angels send prayers on the Prophet: O ye that believe! Send ye prayers on him, and salute him with all respect.
—Al-Ahzab[5]

Answer (score 2):

Love and Respect are the main reasons...

PLUS

There is some legal aspect to it - as is mentioned in the Hadith (At-Tirmithi, 3545):

> It was narrated that Abu Hurayrah (may Allaah be pleased with him)
>   said: The Messenger of Allaah (peace and blessings of Allaah be upon
>   him) said: “May his nose be rubbed in the dust, a man in whose
>   presence I am mentioned and he does not send blessings upon me.”

There are other Hadiths with similar meaning... for further information see:

- http://www.islam-qa.com/en/68837
- http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Peace_be_upon_him_%28Islam%29