# Why is the prayer or dua "peace be upon him" used for someone not alive?

Tags: sunnah, dua

To pray for someone to have God's blessings and God's peace only makes literal sense for someone who is alive and in the mist of the trails and tribulations of this world. After all, to be at peace in this world is almost universally, nearly intuitively, accepted as a sign of success in this life that transcends status or wealth - sometimes in spite of it.

For someone who is not alive what good is it to have someone pray for them to have peace and blessings from God?

I understand praying for God to forgive or have mercy on them, or paying debts for someone who has passed away because this could have an impact on Judgement day through God's mercy and forgiveness.

I think the answer is that it is only an action of love for the people who are responsible for faithfully relaying the bountiful message of Islam with all of its knowledge and blessings.

These questions talk about the subject of "pbuh":

- [The rules](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/140/what-are-the-rules-of-saying-peace-be-upon-him?s=1%7C2.4855)
- [The purpose](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/1/why-do-muslims-add-peace-be-upon-him-after-names-of-important-people?s=4%7C2.1614)
- [How did it start](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/2799/whence-came-pbuh?s=11%7C0.4423)

These surahs are used to answer the links above:

> And peace be upon him the day he was born and the day he dies and the day he is raised alive. [Quran 19:15]
>
> Indeed, Allah confers blessing upon the Prophet, and His angels [ask Him to do so]. O you who have believed, ask [ Allah to confer] blessing upon him and ask [ Allah to grant him] peace. [Quran 33:56]
>
> [Jesus] said, "Indeed, I am the servant of Allah . He has given me the Scripture and made me a prophet. And He has made me blessed wherever I am and has enjoined upon me prayer and zakah as long as I remain alive And [made me] dutiful to my mother, and He has not made me a wretched tyrant. And peace is on me the day I was born and the day I will die and the day I am raised alive." [Quran 19:30-33]

Comment: Like Rest In Peace?  RIP

Comment: @Sayyid Yeah, its seems to be like that practice of saying "rest in peace", but the references in the Quran are prayers of peace that is either while the person is alive or refers to a day in the future when the person is alive.

Comment: The benefit in first place is the reward we get when saying so!

Answer (score 1):

When you say that, you are wishing they'll be in peaceful state. Worldly life in Islam is but a phase. The soul does not die. Even though a dead person does not exist on planet earth, he still exists, and his existence can either be in a peaceful state or in a stressful state (depends on his fate in the hereafter). The existence of people after they die, and before the judgment day occurs in a world called "Barzakh". We don't know anything about the "Barzakh". Not to mention that your very wishes of peace to someone else will bring **you** peace as well, and purifies your heart.
Allah Knows Best.